# Horário Brasileiro no Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, data

estou com um outro problema de data. Meu mysql está com o horário correto, mas ao gravar a data em um input com javascript está gravando em UTC e não em GMT-0300. O que pode ser?

```
<form id="formColeta">
                        <div class="row mx-auto">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-inline col-6">
                            <label class="text-left"><b>Cliente</b></label>
                            <input name="cliente" type="text" value="" id="cliente" placeholder="Cliente" autofocus required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group form-group-inline col-6">
                            <label><b>Telefone</b></label>
                            <input name="telefone" type="number" value="" id="telefone" placeholder="123456789" required>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="form-group form-group-inline col-12 mx-2">
                            <label><b>Observação</b></label>
                            <input class="col-12" name="observacao" type="text" value="" id="observacao" placeholder="Digite informação importante sobre a coleta">
                        </div>
                       
                        <input name="data" type="hidden" id="data" value="<?php
                        $hoje = date('Y-m-d');
                        echo $hoje
                        ?>">
                        <input name="hora" type="hidden" id="hora" value="<?php
                        $agora = date('H:i:s,-0300');
                        echo $agora
                        ?>">
                        <input name="vendedor" type="hidden" id="vendedor" value="Diego">
                        <input name="status" type="hidden" id="status" value="Aberto">


                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Fechar</button>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Inserir Itens">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Esse é o meu Javascript:

```
<script>
           
            function retornarColetas(data) {
                var coletas = "";


                $.each(data, function (chave, valor) {

                    var dataFormatada = valor.data.split('-').reverse().join('/');
                    coletas += '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + valor.id_coleta + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + valor.cliente + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + dataFormatada + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + valor.hora + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + valor.vendedor + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + valor.status + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info text-info mr-2"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Editar</a>' +
                            '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger text-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Excluir</a>' +
                            '</td>';
                });
                $('#tabelaColeta').html(coletas);

            }

            $('#formColeta').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var formulario = $(this);
                var retorno = inserirColeta(formulario);
            });

            function inserirColeta(dados) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: dados.serialize(),
                    url: "config/insertcoleta.php",
                    async: "false"
                }).then(sucesso, falha);

                function sucesso(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }

                function falha() {
                    console.log("erro");

                }


            }

        </script>
```

Comment: Qual tipo da coluna no Mysql? Como está o php que recebe os dados do formulário e insere no banco?

Comment: Damião, esses dados estão numa coluna de dataTables

Answer (score -1):

Eu utilizaria um php no início da página:

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
  $hoje = date('d/m/Y');
  $agora = date('H:i');
?>
```